Boundary Value Problem for an Indeterminate Beam using Finite Difference Method
I hope I am in the right place!
I am trying to solve an indertminate beam using the finite difference method in MATLAB. I am using the fourth order equation to do this:
enter image description here
My beam is an 8m long beam with a pinned support at x = 0, and roller supports at x = 4 and x = 8. It is under a constant distrbuted load of 10 kN/m.
Firstly, I want to find the displacements of the beam, and I am comparing the results to a software package.
The maxium deflection in the software package is 0.347mm
Here is my code using the FDM:
% Structural Properties
E = 2.1E+08
I = 18890/100^4
EI = E*I


% Attemp with 31 points
N = 31;
L = 8
x = linspace(0,L,N)
h = L/(N-1)
q = 10


% Construct matrix
mat1 = diag(ones(1,N)*6) ;                              
mat2 = diag(ones(1,N-1)*-4, 1);
mat3 = diag(ones(1,N-1)*-4, -1);
mat4 = diag(ones(1,N-2)*1, 2);
mat5 = diag(ones(1,N-2)*1, -2);

matrix = [mat1 + mat2 + mat3 + mat4 + mat5]


% Create right-hand side

Lambda = EI/h^4

rhs = (ones(1,N))*(q)/Lambda
rhs = rhs'


% Remove rows where displacement is zero

matrix(:,[1,N,(N+1)/2]) = [];
matrix([1,N,(N+1)/2],:) = [];
rhs([1,N,(N+1)/2]) = []

% Find displacement in mm
y = ((inv(matrix)*rhs))*1000

And here are my results from MATLAB:
    0
    0.0210
    0.0544
    0.0928
    0.1300
    0.1614
    0.1833
    0.1934
    0.1908
    0.1758
    0.1498
    0.1158
    0.0778
    0.0412
    0.0126
         0
    0.0126
    0.0412
    0.0778
    0.1158
    0.1498
    0.1758
    0.1908
    0.1934
    0.1833
    0.1614
    0.1300
    0.0928
    0.0544
    0.0210
         0

The maximum deflection is 0.1934mm
Obviously, this doesn't match the software's results and I am a little stuck as to why. Could someone plaese help?
Here is the results from the software:

Many thanks,
Scott

Are you expecting the solution to go up and down twice?

Hi Wolfgang Bangerth, yes, I am. Please see the image from the software that I have just attached.

Do you have another test case with an analytical solution? The first thing to do is to check that you can reproduce that solution and assess the effective order of convergence of your scheme. Maybe your code or the other software is wrong, or maybe you are not using enough points. Also, your equation does not seem to be displayed... Also, please add the boundary conditions.

Thanks guys, all solved now. Stupidly, I forgot that for a 4th order differential equation I need 4 boundary conditions. At first I was only using the boundary conditions for the displacement. After adding the boundary conditions for the moments (x=0,M=0) and (x=L,M=0) I got the corect answer. Thanks Laurent90 for jogging my memory when you said please add the boundary conditions.

Feel free to write and submit an answer to your own question so that it is marked "answered"
